# Source files not found in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to create a Cocoapod. I used the steps listed on their website to do so; however, now that I am trying to create the sample app I'm running into issues. It finds and auto completes the Module, however it says "Undefined Type" for anything I have defined in Classes:

**Podfile:**
[image: podfile]

**Podspec:**
[image: podspec]

**Class attempting to use the pod:**
[image: class]

**Protocol defined in the pod, included in the correct project:**
[image: protocol]

Not sure what is going on but when I Command+Click on the highlighted protocols in image 3 it does link me to the correct files in the pod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try declaring your protocol as public, since your pod exists in a different module, and the default access permission is internal.

Comment: That is it! i was unaware of that defualt. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that fixed it. One other item, by declaring that protocol as public, it will expose all of its properties and methods as well. Should you not want to do that, then you can specify them as either internal or private to prevent that from happening.